# XA4211: AndroidManifest.xml //uses-sdk/@android:targetSdkVersion '33' is less than $(TargetFrameworkVersion) ''

Tags: android, maui

I need to target a .NET MAUI app to Android API 33, however, when building, this warning appears.

I see that $(TargetFrameworkVersion) is defined as '' even when in my project properties, is explicitly specified:

[image]

How can I solve it?

Comment: Could you please show the content of `AndroidManifest.xaml` under Resources\Android\Platform?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce it and the warning only appears when setting the following in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />`
```

Since it's a warning, you can ignore it in general. Also, you can create a `.NET 7` project which will omit or get rid of the warning in this scenario.